# onKeyUp() and onKeyDown() have some issue

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I am trying to call some event in ctrl+c or ctrl+d in a android app with help of external keyboard.For this what have done is as below

```
         @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT){
          flag_sellreceipt=KeyEvent.isModifierKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT);
        }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D && flag_sellreceipt) {
        HotkeyForDone();
        flag_sellreceipt = false;
    } 
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C && flag_sellreceipt) {
        try {
            cancelCart();
            flag_sellreceipt = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleException(Present.this, e,"In some screen" + e.toString(),null);
            e.printStackTrace();
            flag_sellreceipt = false;
        }
    }  
   }
```

This is working fine as i wish but there is some thing happen which is undesirable. Ctrl+d or Ctrl+c together working fine , but what is happening suppose user only press ctrl and after some time user press d or c then Ctrl+d or Ctrl+c is invoking which is really undesirable event. It should only happen when ctrl and alphabet press simultaneously. Can any body help me to resolve this issue , or please suggest me any idea to get me out of  this issue. thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
      @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT){
         flag_sellreceipt = false;
     }
     }
```

And

```
        @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT){
          flag_sellreceipt=KeyEvent.isModifierKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT);
         int i = KeyEvent.META_CTRL_LEFT_ON;
         System.out.println("ctrl is pressed");
        }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to program it like that?  Try the keyboard on your PC-  if you hold control for 2 minutes then hit c, its still a ctrl+c because you still have control held.

If you do really want to do this for some odd reason, keep the time when the control key was pressed.  In onKeyUp, if the control key was pressed more than X milliseconds ago (where x is some reasonable value like 200 or so) clear the fllag you're using to mark control as down.

Comment: @gabe...thanks for your quick response. Is it possible to catch a event that happen how milliseconds earlier.  ?

Comment: No.  You have to save off the timestamp in a variable when the first event happens.